# Why does SQL Server 2005 only use an IS lock in this scenario?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, locking

I am attempting to examine the locking behind different queries but with the same output to avoid deadlocking situations.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT MIN(ID),
    TextData
FROM
    PKKEYTESTER
GROUP BY
    TextData
ORDER BY
    TextData DESC
```

The locking for the code is as follows:

```
IS Lock:Acquired
IS Lock:Acquired
IS Lock:Released
IS Lock:Released
```

At no point does it get a S lock.

So why does it intend to get a shared lock but actually doesn't?

SQL To create and insert base data into table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PKKEYTESTER](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Textdata] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO PKKEYTESTER 
VALUES (1, 'A')

INSERT INTO PKKEYTESTER 
VALUES (2, 'B')
```

Comment: Is this a small table? How many rows does this table hold?

Comment: How do you obtaion the _"locking for the code"_?

Comment: The table only has two records (example table). Locking is gained using SQL Profiler. If I change the query to use TOP 1 instead of MIN I get the shared lock as expected. However I just want to understand why IS locks are being taken without resulting in a shared lock, is it because of the range scan?

Comment: `TOP 1 .. GROUP BY ... ORDER BY` vs. `MIN ... GROUP BY` give **a different semantically query**. I recommend you post **exact** table definition along with test data you use.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the create table statement and data I am using.

Comment: https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2010/11/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.html